# django {% url %} template looping

Tags: python, django, django-models

my url.py

```
app_name="application_name"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^staff/",include('application_name.staff_url', namespace='staff')),
    url(r"^customer/",include('application_name.customer_url', namespace='customer')),
]
```

staff_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="staff"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^customers/",views.customers, name='customers'),
    url(r"^orders/$", views.orders, name='orders'),
    url(r"^payments/$", views.payments, name='payments'),
]
```

customer_url.py

```
from application_name import views
app_name="customer"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r"^items/",views.items, name='items'),
    url(r"^checkout/$", views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    url(r"^make_payment/$", views.make_payment, name='make_payment'),
]
```

staf url would be `staff/orders` or `staff/payments` customer urls would be `customer/items` or `customer/checkout` etc

In my view file I have put every link inside a list which would be iterated inside the template and placed it inside a session

This is my view.py

```
staffLink=[
    {'linkfield':"customers", 'name':"Customers",'slug':"staff"},
    {'linkfield':"orders", 'name':"Orders",'slug':"staff"},
    {'linkfield':"payments", 'name':"payments",'slug':"staff"}]
                    
links=staffLink
request.session['links']= links
request.session['sub']= 'staff'

context_dict = {'links':links}
```

This is my html template

```
{% for link in request.session.links %}
    {% if request.session.sub =="staff" %}
        <a href="{% url  'application_name:staff' link.linkfield as the_url %}" class="nav-link">
    {% elif request.session.sub =="customer" %}
        <a href="{% url  'application_name:customer' link.linkfield as the_url %}" class="nav-link">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Pl

This are the following result

1. When I include the if statement i.e. `{% if request.session.sub =="staff" %}`. The following error is produced

   django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '=="staff"' from '=="staff"'
2. When I exclude the if statement so making it just `<a href="{% url  'application_name:staff' link.linkfield as the_url %}" class="nav-link">`
   I did this for testing purposes. I get the following error

   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'staff' not found. 'staff' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Please what am I to do to get the if statement working alongside the anchor statement

Answer (score 1):

You should write a space between the `==` and the `"staff"` string, so:

```
{% if request.session.sub == "staff" %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

as for the URL, you not refer to a URL which is an `include(…)` since that is a *collection* of URLs. For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'staff:customers' link.linkfield as the_url %}" class="nav-link">
```

Comment: Thanks the space worked. But I tried `"{% url 'customers' link.linkfield as the_url %}"` and `"{% url 'application_name:customers' link.linkfield as the_url %}"`
It was showing me the url of the page where I entered into `someurl/application_name/customers ` not `someurl/application_name/customers/current_page`

Comment: @willen-van-onsem please i am also a little confused about this statememt u made -->"""  ** as for the URL, you not refer to a URL which is an `include(…)` since that is a collection of URLs. For example: **

Comment: `include(..., name='foo')`, means the urls you included have `'foo:'` as URL namespace.

Comment: if i get u correctly i do not need to include `application_name` ?

Comment: @SMev: indeed, that should be `foo` if `foo` is the `name=...` of the `include(..)`.

Comment: I have done {% url 'application_name:customers' link.linkfield as the_url %}. But it is showing me only the home page link excluding the links of the various pages which is in the link.linkfield